# ObjectNotFoundException in Hibernate: No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I keep getting the following error on calling `myMethod()` although my hibernate sql trace clearly shows that everything went well and my database does well contain the record with ID=4:

Error Message Stacktra:

```
    DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - Get count of entities of type "UsrProtocol" from db with propertyName=id and propertyValue=6
DEBUG SQL - select count(*) as col_0_0_ from usr_protocol usrp0_ where usrp0_.id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [6]
TRACE BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
UsrProtocol id exists:true
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "UsrProtocol" shall be deleted from db. ID:6
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "UsrProtocol" has been deleted from db. ID:6
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - Get count of entities of type "UsrProtocol" from db with propertyName=id and propertyValue=6
DEBUG SQL - delete from user_activity where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [240]
DEBUG SQL - delete from activity where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [240]
DEBUG SQL - delete from usr_file where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [6]
DEBUG SQL - delete from usr_protocol where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [6]
DEBUG SQL - select count(*) as col_0_0_ from usr_protocol usrp0_ where usrp0_.id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [6]
TRACE BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [0]
UsrProtocol id exists:false
resource id :42
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "Resource" shall be deleted from db. ID:42
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "Resource" has been deleted from db. ID:42
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "Usr" shall be updated in db. ID:15
DEBUG SQL - select usrp0_.id as id1_16_0_, usrp0_.comment as comment2_16_0_, usrp0_.protocol_date as protocol3_16_0_, usrp0_.usr_id as usr_id4_16_0_, usrp0_.admin_id as usr_fruu5_16_0_, usrp0_2_.resource_id as resource2_15_0_, case when usrp0_1_.id is not null then 1 when usrp0_2_.id is not null then 2 when usrp0_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_0_ from usr_protocol usrp0_ left outer join usr_comment usrp0_1_ on usrp0_.id=usrp0_1_.id left outer join usr_file usrp0_2_ on usrp0_.id=usrp0_2_.id where usrp0_.id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]
INFO  DefaultLoadEventListener - HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.tud.db.entities.UsrProtocol#4]
Aug 17, 2018 12:33:31 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
WARNUNG: #{actionBean[yesButtonAction]}: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.tud.db.entities.UsrProtocol#4]
javax.faces.FacesException: #{actionBean[yesButtonAction]}: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.tud.db.entities.UsrProtocol#4]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFERROR TPMExceptionHandler - javax.faces.FacesException: #{actionBean[yesButtonAction]}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = 
    Logger.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<UsrProtocol> UsrProtocolDao;
    /*other source code has been omitted*/

    @Override
    public void myMethod(){
         /*other source code has been omitted*/
         System.out.println("UsrProtocol id exists:"+UsrProtocolDao.exists(UsrProtocol));
         UsrProtocolDao.remove(UsrProtocol);
         System.out.println("UsrProtocol id exists:"+UsrProtocolDao.exists(UsrProtocol));
    }

}
```

GenericDaoImpl.java

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenericDaoImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public GenericDaoImpl(final Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public GenericDaoImpl(final Class<T> type, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.type = type;
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(final T entity) {
        return entity.getId() == null ? false : getCountAllByProperty("id", entity.getId()) > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(final T removeObject) {
        log.debug("An entity of type \"" + type.getSimpleName() + "\" shall be deleted from db. ID:" + removeObject.getId());
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(removeObject);
        log.debug("An entity of type \"" + type.getSimpleName() + "\" has been deleted from db. ID:" + removeObject.getId());
        return true;
    }

    //other dao methods such as add, lookup, getAll have been omitted
}
```

Log trace output :

```
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - Get count of entities of type "UsrProtocol" from db with propertyName=id and propertyValue=4
DEBUG SQL - select count(*) as col_0_0_ from usr_protocol usrp0_ where usrp0_.id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]
TRACE BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
UsrProtocol id exists:true

DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "UsrProtocol" shall be deleted from db. ID:4
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - An entity of type "UsrProtocol" has been deleted from db. ID:4
DEBUG GenericDaoImpl - Get count of entities of type "UsrProtocol" from db with propertyName=id and propertyValue=4
DEBUG SQL - delete from usr_file where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]
DEBUG SQL - delete from usr_protocol where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]

DEBUG SQL - select count(*) as col_0_0_ from usr_protocol usrp0_ where usrp0_.id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]
TRACE BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [0]
UsrProtocol id exists:false
```

UsrProtocol.java

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "usr_protocol")
public abstract class UsrProtocol implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Admin admin;
    private Usr usr;
    private Date protocolDate;
    private String comment;

    public UsrProtocol() {
    }

    public UsrProtocol(final Admin admin, final Usr usr, final Date protocolDate, final String comment) {
        this.admin = admin;
        this.usr = usr;
        this.protocolDate = protocolDate;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", nullable = false)
    public Admin getAdmin() {
        return this.admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(final Admin admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usr_id", nullable = false)
    public Usr getUsr() {
        return this.usr;
    }

    public void setUsr(final Usr usr) {
        this.usr = usr;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "protocol_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getProtocolDate() {
        return this.protocolDate;
    }

    public void setProtocolDate(final Date protocolDate) {
        this.protocolDate = protocolDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "comment", nullable = false, length = 500)
    public String getComment() {
        return this.comment;
    }

    public void setComment(final String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

}
```

UsrFile.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr_file")
public class UsrFile extends UsrProtocol implements java.io.Serializable {

    private ResourceFile resourceFile;

    public UsrFile() {
    }

    public UsrFile(final ResourceFile resourceFile) {
        this.resourceFile = resourceFile;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", nullable = false)
    public ResourceFile getResourceFile() {
        return this.resourceFile;
    }

    public void setResourceFile(final ResourceFile resourceFile) {
        this.resourceFile = resourceFile;
    }
}
```

Querying both tables `usr_protocol` and `usr_file` returns the following :

```
 select * from usr_protocol
```

[image: select * from usr_protocol]

```
 select * from usr_file
```

[image: select * from usr_file]

**UPDATE** : The problem does not concern only UsrProtocol with ID=4 but other records whose ID=5 and ID=6 as well!

Comment: Can you share you dao too?

Comment: Also please share the full stacktrace too if possible.

Comment: Uhhh... looks like you're deleting it `DEBUG SQL - delete from usr_file where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]
DEBUG SQL - delete from usr_protocol where id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]`

Comment: @Aris_Kortex : Thread has been updated, although I could not put the whole trace because of the maximum number of characters.

Comment: @shinjw : The point is I want to delete the UsrProtocol with ID=4 but I am getting the error mentioned above instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should detect why following select is generated:

```
DEBUG SQL - select usrp0_.id as id1_16_0_, usrp0_.comment as comment2_16_0_, usrp0_.protocol_date as protocol3_16_0_, usrp0_.usr_id as usr_id4_16_0_, usrp0_.admin_id as usr_fruu5_16_0_, usrp0_2_.resource_id as resource2_15_0_, case when usrp0_1_.id is not null then 1 when usrp0_2_.id is not null then 2 when usrp0_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_0_ from usr_protocol usrp0_ left outer join usr_comment usrp0_1_ on usrp0_.id=usrp0_1_.id left outer join usr_file usrp0_2_ on usrp0_.id=usrp0_2_.id where usrp0_.id=?
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [4]
```

Your entity has been deleted and that's why above select query raise loading issue